# Sonos Api: Is there a way to understand which Sonos favorite is playing?

Tags: sonos

I want to understand which favorite playlist is currently playing on my Sonos speaker.

I've tried the following options:

- There's no favorite ID in playbackMetadata and in playbackStatus. So, matching with favorite ID doesn't work
- There's containerId in playbackMetadata, which sort of gives information about provider-specific playlist identifiers. Yet, there's no same identifiers in getFavorites response. So, matching containerId won't work either.
- Tried loadingFavorite (both with and without playOnComplete set), then getting playbackMetadata in order to build a mapping of favorite ID to containerId. No luck either. Even with 2s delay between two calls to give some space for favorite to be loaded, playlistMetadata returns old containerId (or it might be new, only it doesn't get changed for a new favorite).

Is there a straightforward option? Or not that straightforward, but working?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible, at least at the UPnP level. When a Favorite is submitted for playback, nothing is included that would allow tracking it back to its origin.